# Some sentences are stored in double quotes and some sentences are stored in csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv
data = open("/home/arushi/PycharmProjects/.../F1.csv", "r")
csvReader = csv.reader(data,
                   quotechar='"',
                   delimiter=(','),
                   quoting =csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                   skipinitialspace=True,
                   escapechar='\\')
header = next(csvReader)
MIndex = header.index("Message")
Messages = []
for row in csvReader:
   m = row[MIndex]
   Messages.append(m)
print(Messages)
```

/home/arushi/...../try9.py

> ['Hi. How are you?', 'I am fine. What about you?', 'I am also good.',
>   'Good to hear that.', "Let's discuss last night's party.", "No. I
>   don't think that will be healthy.", 'I agree with him.', "I don't
>   think we are on the same page.", 'I think we should actually discuss
>   it so that things get cleared.', 'Things may get messed up even
>   more.', "It's better to sort out things.", 'Ya otherwise there will be
>   a lot of misunderstanding..', 'Okay fine.', "That's the spirit!",
>   "Same here. I think it's fine.", 'Finally we are all on the same
>   page.', 'I am just happy we are all still friends.', "I don't want to
>   lose you guys.", 'We will be friends forever.', 'Yeah']

Process finished with exit code 0

Excpected output:

> ["Hi. How are you?","I am fine. What about you?", "I am also good.",
>   "Good to hear that.", "Let's discuss last night's party.", "No. I
>   don't think that will be healthy.", "I agree with him.", "I don't
>   think we are on the same page.", "I think we should actually discuss
>   it so that things get cleared.", "Things may get messed up even
>   more.", "It's better to sort out things.", "Ya otherwise there will be
>   a lot of misunderstanding..", "Okay fine.", "That's the spirit!",
>   "Same here. I think it's fine.", "Finally we are all on the same
>   page.", "I am just happy we are all still friends.", "I don't want to
>   lose you guys.", "We will be friends forever.", "Yeah"]

I want to read a column from a csv file, that contain English language sentences, into a list.

My csv file contain 7 columns of different types having 20 entries.

Should I change my file format? If yes, then which format supports text, date, time, numbers and characters.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 on a 8GB-64bit laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual output and your expected output are in all important respects the same.

```
>>> a = ['Hi. How are you?', 'I am fine. What about you?', 'I am also good.', 'Good to hear that.', "Let's discuss last night's party.", "No. I don't think that will be healthy.", 'I agree with him.', "I don't think we are on the same page.", 'I think we should actually discuss it so that things get cleared.', 'Things may get messed up even more.', "It's better to sort out things.", 'Ya otherwise there will be a lot of misunderstanding..', 'Okay fine.', "That's the spirit!", "Same here. I think it's fine.", 'Finally we are all on the same page.', 'I am just happy we are all still friends.', "I don't want to lose you guys.", 'We will be friends forever.', 'Yeah']
>>> b = ["Hi. How are you?","I am fine. What about you?", "I am also good.", "Good to hear that.", "Let's discuss last night's party.", "No. I don't think that will be healthy.", "I agree with him.", "I don't think we are on the same page.", "I think we should actually discuss it so that things get cleared.", "Things may get messed up even more.", "It's better to sort out things.", "Ya otherwise there will be a lot of misunderstanding..", "Okay fine.", "That's the spirit!", "Same here. I think it's fine.", "Finally we are all on the same page.", "I am just happy we are all still friends.", "I don't want to lose you guys.", "We will be friends forever.", "Yeah"]
>>> a == b
True
```

When you do

```
print(Messages)
```

you are relying on Python's built-in representation of lists of strings. It chooses to prefer `'` over `"` in simple cases. It uses double quotes only in cases like `"No. I don't think that will be healthy."` If you want to see the list of strings in a different format on the screen then you have to do your own formatting.

But there is really no need to do that. If you are planning to do further processing, what matters is the data structure and what is in it, not how its default representation appears on the screen.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response. Yes, I am doing further processing as well. I am using extractOne function to do string matching with a sentence to see which out of these sentences best matches my sentence. My code is:                                                                           from fuzzywuzzy import process                                                    Response = "How are you doing?"
actual_response = process.extractOne(Response, Messages)

print(actual_response)

Comment: `from fuzzywuzzy import process                                                      Response = "How are you doing?"
actual_response = process.extractOne(Response, Messages)
print(actual_response)`                                                                               The output error reads as follows:                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arushi/../try9.py", line 24, in <module>
    actual_response = process.extractOne(Response, Messages)
TypeError: Required argument 'string' (pos 2) not found

Comment: This looks like a completely different question. Please post a new question, rather than putting it in a comment. Your code is very hard to read that way.

Comment: I'll ask this question separately then.